# javascript links and SEO

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

Due to a reason we are making anchor text using javascript and on images we are using method:

```
img onclick="PageTracker('Home » Article Popup', 'Home');" alt="" src=""
```

Is there any version for linking internal pages in JavaScript which is more search engine friendly?

One more thing I need to open new url in pop up as well.

Comment: Please remove Java tag.